# Do widget options need to be escaped widget()?

Tags: plugins, customization, widgets

I was wondering if you really need to escape user submitted data (widget option fields) within the widget() and form() functions (from the widget class) ?

I don't see a reason to do this, if the data is already escaped in the update() function. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mm, they're not slashed, if that's what your meaning.

However, they're definitely not xss-sanitized. Use kses before saving, or esc_attr() on display, if you're dealing with untrusted data.

Comment: yes, but I wanted to know if you are required to sanitize them even when you're retrieving these options from the database. It just doesn't seem necessary to do that...

Comment: That would depend if you sanitized them before storing them in the database.